# Header is jumping in Bootstrap column-ratio when moving <body>

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The header in the head of the page is set to a 1-10-1 column ratio. When the menu at the left of the page appears the whole `<body>` is moving `185px` to the right. At first view, the header is moving to the right but once there he will jump back into 1-10-1 position. Why is the header ignoring this moving command? I thought about setting some `position` to `absolute` or `fixed` but this is ruining may layout (of the header).

*with some specific zoom-specification of your browser it is working well, but once changing this zoom to another position it fails (like described above) (Ctrl + '-' or CMD + '-' for resp. Windows or Mac I believe)

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JFP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="body-wrapper">
<div class="menu">
        <div class="icon-close">
            <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
                <div class="icon-menu">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
                <li><a>!</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
            </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {}

body{
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
    left: -185px;
    height: 200%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 185px;
}

.menu ul {
    border-top: 1px solid #636366;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.header {
}

.header i {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.header a{
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header .col-md-10 {
    background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
    width: 85%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
}

.container-fluid {
    max-width: none;
}



.footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.footer p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .main h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        padding: 0 40px;
    }
    .supporting .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".icon-menu").click(function() {
    $(".menu").animate({
    left: "0px"
    }, 600);
    $(".icon-menu").toggle(1600);

    $("body").animate({
    left: "185px"
    }, 600);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
    left: "-185px"
    }, 600);
    $(".icon-menu").toggle(600);

    $('body').animate({
    left: "0px"
    }, 600);
    });
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwwPjQ)